# How to turn off Chromium Xmarks history sync?

Tags: sync, chromium, history, xmarks

In Chromium I get "Changes to sync" notification with Xmarks as soon as I open a new website. I believe it wants to sync my history, and I would like to turn that off since I want only my bookmarks synced and not my history... In Firefox there is an option to turn off history sync but, in Chromium I don't see that anywhere.. Does anyone know a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could possibly be syncing open tabs. Checked that? Cause Xmark on Chrone doesn't sync history.

Edit:

Come to think of it.  It IS.  I remember Xmark has that warning from Chome saying something like this extension will have access to your history. . .

Comment: well, from the log it looks like it is trying to sync tabs all the time, but it can't because I turned it off.. weird.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Chrome Sync enabled? if yes, I think you should disable it.

Click on the wrench icon, select **Options**, **Personal Stuff**. Under **Sync** click **Stop syncing this account**.

[image]